Group a paragraph and a table so they don't get split across pages
I am trying to add a caption for a table and then immediately after, add a table. Sometimes the table and caption get split across multiple pages because of table size, etc. Is there anything similar to https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.parfmt.ParagraphFormat.keep_together that can be used with both paragraphs and tables.
This is simply the format I am currently using. The caption comes first by way of a run in the paragraph, then comes the table. I need to make sure they get page-wrapped together.
from docx import Document

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Table 1.1 -- Caption Text')

table = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=4)


IF you just want to add comment have you tried using this should give you better line control .
'''
 ur para line1
 ur para line 2
 ...so  on?
'''


Doesn't accomplish what I am trying to do. So the problem I am having is it will bump the table down to the next page. I need the table and caption to stay together.

Wierd for me your code is working as expected ,what is the actual rows and column size you are trying with.?

What I am saying is if the caption fits on the bottom of a page and the table doesn't, I want both to snap to the next page.
